# How does Ubuntu 18.04 handle gnome extension settings?

Tags: gnome

For my Ubuntu 18.04.3 setup, I installed Clock override, Activities Configurator and Dash to Panel gnome extensions to modify the top panel. I can utilize Gnome Tweaks to change the settings as well as the gnome extension website. As I mentioned in response to another question, I had issues with the extension Dynamic Panel Transparency, so I went into /usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/ubuntu.css and changed the settings there so that I can get a near Transparent panel.

As I understand the desktop environment during initialization reads ubuntu.css to prepare the GUI environment. I assume that next, extension settings are read to override the settings previously prepared. How does extensions exactly influence the GUI environment?

After initial posting: I went into the settings of Activities configurator extension to change the panel transparency to 70% and color to Red (FF0000).  Then, in Dash to panel I changed the panel transparency to 50% and color Blue (00FF00).  The result is a purple panel with some transparent qualities. So, there is a blending process happening with extensions.

To be honest, I do not know where to begin to search the answer to this question other than reading initialization process for Linux, which I have, but that didn't cover extension handling.

What I am looking for is similar to function calling in programming, but more broad spectrum, I guess.  To be specific, what file, process or application of the desktop environment is being influenced by the extensions that modify the top panel?  I know that the global ubuntu.css file isn't being modified on shutdown to save current settings.

The reason, I am asking this is the time between login authentication passed and GUI is up and running is longer than that should be. And more important, 'cause I wanna know. More ya know and all that.

Comment: @PRATAP, I am trying to understand how extensions are handled during startup and during realtime.  I am assuming they are calling a window property in the GUI desktop application suite.  My main goal is to understand so that I can somehow fix a time delay between login authentication and GUI is up and running. I am using Top Panel attributes as a specific case as a road to the big picture.

Comment: I have seen few posts which are worried about the top bar colors panel transparency etc.. thought you are also in the same line... any ways.. I dont know about what you are looking for..